# Pyspark - why isupper(), islower(), istitle() doesnt work in udf?

Tags: python, string, apache-spark, pyspark

I tried to create udf to check if a name string is all upper case or lower case.
why it is not producing what I was expecting?
For example:

```
def check_case(name):
  if name.isupper() : check="yes"  
  else : check="no" 
  return check

my_udf = udf(lambda x: check_case(name), StringType())

df.withColumn("casecheck",my_udf(col("firstName"))).select("firstName","casecheck").show()
```

the output is below which clearly is wrong. I tried to use islower(), istitle() , also produced wrong result. (it will return all yes or all no for all records).
any idea why it is not working in udf?

thank you!

```
+---------+---------+
|firstName|casecheck|
+---------+---------+
| GRETCHEN|       no|
|   IFswkG|       no|
|    April|       no|
```

I also tried this:

```
def check_case(name):
  if name.isupper() : check="yes"  
  else : check="no" 
  return check

my_udf = udf(check_case, StringType())

df.withColumn("casecheck",my_udf("firstName")).select("firstName","casecheck").show()
```

now I am getting error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1046.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 385.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 385.0 (TID 9580, ip-10-22-10-102.ec2.internal, executor 32): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1598626762284_0001/container_1598626762284_0001_01_000061/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1598626762284_0001/container_1598626762284_0001_01_000061/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1598626762284_0001/container_1598626762284_0001_01_000061/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 248, in <lambda>
    func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1598626762284_0001/container_1598626762284_0001_01_000061/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1598626762284_0001/container_1598626762284_0001_01_000061/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in check_case
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isupper'
```

more edit:

```
def check_case(name):
   if name != None and name.isupper() : check="yes"     
   elif name!= None and  name.islower() : check="no"   
   else : check= None
   return check 

my_udf = udf(check_case, StringType())

df.withColumn("casecheck",my_udf("firstName")).select("firstName","casecheck").show()
```

output is

```
+---------+---------+
|firstName|casecheck|
+---------+---------+
| GRETCHEN|      yes|
| GRETCHEN|      yes|
| GRETCHEN|      yes|
| Christos|     null|
|   IFswkG|     null|
|    April|     null|
|  MATTHEW|      yes|
|     riUj|     null|
|    HARRY|      yes|
```

Comment: @A.B  thank you. I changed that and now I have error. I edited my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you are passing `name` not `x` through your lambda function, you need to just specify the function in udf, lambda isnt required.

```
my_udf = udf(check_case, StringType())
```

In your function you need to handle None and isupper islower condition as

```
def check_case(name):
    if name!= None and (name.isupper() or name.islower()):
       check = "yes"
    else :
       check= "no" 
    return check
```

Also, You can have a simpler and efficient(udf can be more expensive) solution by making a column like this

```
df.withColumn("casecheck",
when((col("firstName") != None) 
& (col("firstname").isupper() | col("firstname").islower()), "yes")
.otherwise("no"))
.select("firstName","casecheck").show()
```

Comment: My goal was actually to detect mix-case, so if the firstName is "JoHn", i would like to be alerted.

Comment: Did udf thing i described helped?

Comment: thanks! I tried that but didnt work...I updated my original post with that. thank you!

Comment: Can you try this and let me know what happens?
`if name != None and name.isupper() : check="yes"  
  elif name!= None and  name.islower() : check="no"
  else check= None
return check
`

Comment: interesting...something did happen. I updated my post.

Comment: Can you please eloborate your expected output? what should be the output in these cases 1. GRETCHEN 2.grethcen 3.Grechen 4.ifswkG

Comment: According to my understanding, you want `yes` if you have `all lowercase` or `all upercase` (GRETCHEN,grethcen) and no if mixed (Grechen ,ifswkG). If this is right, I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

By using `rdd`,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], 'no' if x[1] is None or x[1].islower()  else 'yes')) \
  .toDF(df.columns + ['case_check']).show()

+---+---------+----------+
| id|firstName|case_check|
+---+---------+----------+
|  1|        A|       yes|
|  2|        a|        no|
|  3|        B|       yes|
|  4|        b|        no|
|  5|     null|        no|
|  6|       Dd|       yes|
|  7|       eE|       yes|
+---+---------+----------+
```